# Using skin in C++ Builder XE5 causes window overflow from screen

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I'm using C++ Builder XE5 and building a VCL Form Application. I'm using custom style named 'Carbon'. When I maximize application window in my 2nd screen, which is located right, I can see the 3px of my form from 1st screen. Form is overflowing from my screen.

I changed styles but same problem occurs in other styles also. You can see this problem in blank new project, I mean nothing in my code cause this. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a XE5 (or VCL) specific issue? I think I have the same problem/behavior with normal Windows apps.

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't work on other platforms with styling.

Comment: I meant that if you check for instance, Notepad, doesn't it do the same? I believe that it might be an issue of the OS, not the apps or compiler or styling itself.

Comment: voted to close as this is nothing to do with programming or the listed apps;  nearly all maximised apps give this effect